# Local storage in Firefox does not work with TableFilter

Tags: javascript, firefox

Currently I'm using [TableFilter](https://github.com/koalyptus/TableFilter) which filters my tables very well but unfortunately I can't get it store infortmations via the local_storage configuration in my Firefox (Version: 45.2.0).

```
var tfConfig = {
    base_path: '/assets/js/',
    col_1: 'checklist',
    alternate_rows: true,
    rows_counter: true,
    rows_counter_text: "Entries: ",
    btn_reset: true,
    btn_reset_text: "Clear",
    loader: true,
    status_bar: true,
    no_results_message: true,
    state: {
       types: ['local_storage_xxxx'],
       filters: true,
       sort: true,
       filters_visibility: true
     },
```

Does someone has an idea where I need to look ? Configuration of Firefox ?

Comment: Is it the config options or the table data that you want to store in localStorage?

Comment: The JS TableFilter will store the currently selected filter into this storage..so if you have a different view you can go back to that one and have the same filter....